# Verify if a checkbox is checked vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know if at least one check box has been checked and I have these lines of code but don't seem to work as I expect. Can anybody help me please? Thank you. When I have it as follows, it will keep on asking the user to check a box even if there is at least one box checked

```
 If Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(0) = False Or Sheet1.ListBox2.Selected(0) = False Then
    MsgBox "Please check a box"
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

If I have it this way, it will not ask the user to check a box even if there is no boxes checked. But there is a box checked then it will ask the user to check at least one box.

```
 If Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True Or Sheet1.ListBox2.Selected(0) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please check a box"
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

Thank you for any help. Also, one more thing FRIENDS, if you are sooo kind to help me since I am new coding please, please help me with very simple lines of code. I honestly hate when I implement intelligent lines of code but I have no idea what it does. I want to learn what the code does so I know for the next time. Thank you thank you.

Comment: Why listboxes in your code? Aren't you using checkboxes?

Comment: I retrieve column titles from an excel sheet, then I add those column titles as checkboxes in a listbox so the user can select which titles he/she wants to work with. But before the user starts working with files I need to make sure the user has also selected at least one checkbox in two listboxes(I have four but if it works for two, it should work for four).

Comment: So you're checking to see if any of the items in a ListBox are selected? Wouldn't you normally just use `Sheet1.ListBox1.ListIndex` ? (If ListIndex is -1, nothing is selected)

Comment: Yes Sir. I am new to programming so I didn't know I could use Sheet1.ListBox1.ListIndex . Not sure how to use it but I will check on google furthermore. I will make the change once I know how and I will let you know.

Comment: Ok, this is what I have still does not work :(.  

If Sheet1.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Or Sheet1.ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please check a box"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Comment: What happens when you use `MsgBox Sheet1.ListBox1.ListIndex` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57781/discussion-between-bart-g-and-tigeravatar).

Answer (score 0):

This will check if at least one chechbox on a sheet has been checked:

```
Sub terraniann()
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, o.Name, "CheckBox") > 0 Then
            If o.Object.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "at least one box has been checked"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "no checkboxes have been checked"
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a fancy code :). Thank you. I implemented it but, it keeps popping up "no checkboxes have been checked" even if I have at least one checkbox checked in every listbox(four).